# Cassandra: For a single node cluster, will keyspace replication factor >1 increase disk space usage?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I have a keyspace with replication factor set to 3 but I have only a single node. Will then the disk space be used 3 times the data size? As the replicas are not yet assigned to any other nodes, will cassandra stop creating replicas unless new nodes join the cluster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the disk space used would not be three times the size.  The single node would own the entire token range and all writes would be written to that single node once.

What happens with the writes for the other two replicas would depend on if those nodes were previously present in the cluster and are currently down, or if they have never been added to the cluster.  If they had never been added, then C* would just skip trying to write to them.

If they had been added but are currently down, and if you have hinted handoffs enabled and are still within the hinted handoff window, then C* will store hints for the down nodes on the single up node.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the replication strategy you have used . Assuming your queries are working you might have used SimpleStrategy  , if you try to write to such a configuration your write should fail as it needs to write to 2 additional replica node before it gives a acknowledgement to the client ,which in case of SimpleStratagy are the next two clockwise nodes in the Ring.

Comment: I'm using "NetworkTopologyStrategy" with replication factor 3, having a single node and all my queries are using consistency level one. So queries aren't failing.